# Docker File to support FTP and SFTP

Tags: docker, ftp, dockerfile, sftp, docker-registry

Currently we are using SFTP server,it is built from below Docker file and it is working fine.  Our requirement is to support both FTP and SFTP Protocol in the same container.  Below is the Dockerfile. Any help will be appreciated.

```
FROM centos

ARG USER_ID=14
ARG GROUP_ID=50


LABEL Description="vsftpd Docker image based on Centos 7. Supports passive mode and virtual users." \
    License="Apache License 2.0" \
    Usage="docker run -d -p [HOST PORT NUMBER]:21 -v [HOST FTP HOME]:/home/vsftpd fauria/vsftpd" \
    Version="1.0"

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN yum install -y \ 
vsftpd \ 
db4-utils \ \n
db4 \ \n
iproute && yum clean all \n

RUN usermod -u ${USER_ID} ftp \n
RUN groupmod -g ${GROUP_ID} ftp \n

ENV FTP_USER **String** \n
ENV FTP_PASS **Random** \n
ENV PASV_ADDRESS **IPv4**\n
ENV PASV_ADDR_RESOLVE NO
ENV PASV_ENABLE YES
ENV PASV_MIN_PORT 21100
ENV PASV_MAX_PORT 21110
ENV XFERLOG_STD_FORMAT NO
ENV LOG_STDOUT **Boolean**
ENV FILE_OPEN_MODE 0666
ENV LOCAL_UMASK 077
ENV REVERSE_LOOKUP_ENABLE YES
COPY vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd/
COPY vsftpd_virtual /etc/pam.d/
COPY run-vsftpd.sh /usr/sbin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/sbin/run-vsftpd.sh
RUN mkdir -p /home/vsftpd/
RUN chown -R ftp:ftp /home/vsftpd/
VOLUME /home/vsftpd
VOLUME /var/log/vsftpd
EXPOSE 20 21 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/run-vsftpd.sh"]
```

Comment: Please tell us what's not working. SO is not a code-as-a-service platform.

Comment: Since FTP and sftp (ssh) are two separate protocols served by two separate daemons, you'd generally want to run these in separate containers.  Putting a username and password in plain text in your Dockerfile, then compiling that into an image where they can be easily extracted, really isn't a best practice, though.